# Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I have nginx with the following setup:

```
 server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  site.com www.site.com;
        root /home/site/public_html;

        listen       443;
        #server_name  site.com www.site.com;
        #root /home/site/public_html;
        ssl_certificate      /root/site.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /root/site.key;
```

However, when I view the SSL connection I am getting:

```
An error occurred during a connection to grewpler.com.

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

I am using `TrustWave Premium SSL` as the SSL cert authority.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Solved. You need to add "ssl" to the end of the listen.

```
listen       443 ssl;
```

Comment: Such a simple thing and so easy to overlook. Thanks!

Comment: I have lost 2 hours trying to find the problem. So easy to miss.

Comment: Bravo, you have saved my day after hours of searching!

Answer (score 4):

This error I got in browser when trying to access site over SSL(https) but in fact on that port normal HTTP server was running.